# How to add new hostname to existing virtual host in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

This is my apache configuration (most interesting part of it):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Works fine and my server properly responds to `example.com:80` HTTP requests. Now I'm going to add an alias to this domain. I want all requests to `my-new-domain.com:80/test` produce the same responses as to `example.com`, for example:

```
my-new-domain.com/test/xyz -> example.com/xyz
```

What is important, I don't want to see HTTP redirections (301 code). I want to hide `example.com` URL from a user. All that he has to see is `my-new-domain.com/test` URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put

```
ServerAlias my-new-domain.com
```

inside the VirtualHost section

for the rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^my-new-domain\.com
RewriteRule /test/(.*)     /$1                   [QSA,L,P]
```

Comment: No, that doesn't deal with the `/test` part.

Comment: Exactly, this is just the first part of the solution. Then I need to use `RewriteRule`s, but can't understand how to specify them properly.. @jamespo can you help?

Comment: many thanks! Btw, do you know how to specify rules when I need to extend URL paths: `my-new-domain.com/xyz -> example.com/test/xyz`?

Answer (score 1):

Use mod_rewrite with mod_proxy (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Otherwise, if domains differ, mod_rewrite performs an external rewrite even if both are served from the same host.

Something like

> RewriteRule ^http://my-new-domain.com/test http://example.com [QSA,P]

Another solution would be to create a symlink `test` in my-new-domain.com’s root dir to the root dir of example.com.

Comment: RewriteRules don't match on the full URL I don't think?